# Client Side only HTML Forms

Tags: html, forms, client

I want to create an HTML form that uses data in the dialog boxes to modify a destination URL in specific spots in the destination URL.

I'm just trying to centralize the location where I enter what I am searching for but it will pass a URL and load the page with the results without me having to first load each separate tools search page, then enter data and wait for results. I looking to remove the middle man of each separate tools search page.

Comment: You want to modify the destination url or the data at the destination url? The former one you can achieve with some javascript (and regular expressions). The latter is not possible client side only.

Comment: yes I want to modify the destination URL. not the data on the resulting page.

Comment: Could you give an example on how the initial url looks like and which parts you want to change?

Comment: @HarielA4 Your question is still rather vague, could you add some (pseudo) code examples showing your issue?

Comment: I need to make a form. The form will accept input that will modify a value in a URL. the blank URL with xxx as the variable is as follows:http://www.yy.com/perl/search?searchtype=loginid&type=4&uid=xxx&visualtype=html%2Fen&tabset=person
I want to be able to replace the variable with the data submited from the text box in the form when the user hits submit. the full completed URL is then loaded as a page. if the uid that is searched for is frank then the completed URL would be the result below:
http://www.yy.com/perl/search?searchtype=loginid&type=4&uid=frank&visualtype=html%2Fen&tabset=person

Comment: This answers my quesiton about how this is done.  I have tested it as working.  During the course of this I have found that I want another feature.  how do I get the result of the form submission to open in a new tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something eg like this;

UPDATE:

HTML form

```
<form>
Search: <input id="search" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="setSearchTerm()" />
</form>
```

javascript

```
<script>
function setSearchTerm(n){
   var UID_VALUE = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("search").value);
   location.href = "http://xx.xxxx.something.com/perl/search?searchtype=loginid&type=4&uid=" + UID_VALUE + "&visualtype=html%2Fen&tabset=person";
 }
</script>
```

you need to change `http://xx.xxxx.something.com` to your the address the search page is running from

Comment: where in that form does it indicate what javascript file to call?

Comment: you wrote `where the person woud put info in the dialog box and hit submit. the form would then add that data into the zzzzzz spot and load the page`, i may of misunderstood you

Comment: so basically the URL is this.

http://xx.xxxx.something.com/perl/search?searchtype=loginid&type=4&uid=zzzzzz&visualtype=html%2Fen&tabset=person

the person enters user ID frank and clicks submit.  the form takes frank and inputs it place of zzzzzz and then loads the URL as the result.

http://xx.xxxx.something.com/perl/search?searchtype=loginid&type=4&uid=frank&visualtype=html%2Fen&tabset=person

Comment: how do i use this code??  I have made a file containing the form code but how do I reference the javascript from that form??

Comment: @HarielA4, just copy and paste both the top and bottom code snippets in a text file, such as notepad and save it as `.htm` or `.html`

Comment: did that and nothing happens when I click the button

Comment: @HarielA4 , please post the code for you page so we can see whats going on/ edit you question

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Search Tool</title>
<script>
function setSearchTerm(n){
   var UID_VALUE = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementbyId("search").value);
   location.href = 'http://xx.xx.something.com/perl/search?searchtype=loginid&type=4&uid=" + UID_VALUE + "&visualtype=html%2Fen&tabset=person";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Search: <input  id="search" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="setSearchTerm()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: sorry I dont know how to make it post in a code box liek you did and I cannt seem to understand what the help says to do to make it show as code